# How to remap and sort references in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

We are trying to generate a "virtual" prop with an "aggregate". The problem is MongoDB's "aggregate" does not work with virtual props.

We have three collections (JUST A DEMO).
The POST:

```
{
_id:'SOME_RANDOM_ID',
name:'SOME_NAME',
comments: ['COMMENT1_REF_ID','COMMENT2_REF_ID']
}
```

TAG:

```
{
    _id:'TAG_RANDOM_ID',
    name:'SOME_NAME',
    author: ['AUTHOR1_REF_ID','AUTHOR2_REF_ID']
}
```

and COMMENT:

```
[{
  _id:'COMMENT1_REF_ID',
  text:'SOME_TEXT',
  date: 'SOME DATE',
  tags: ['TAG1_REF_ID', 'TAG2_REF_ID']
},
{
  _id:'COMMENT2_REF_ID',
  text:'SOME_TEXT',
  date: 'SOME DATE',
  tags: ['TAG1_REF_ID', 'TAG2_REF_ID']
}]
```

The result should be:

```
{
_id:'SOME_RANDOM_ID',
name:'SOME_NAME',
commentsObject: {
  'COMMENT1_REF_ID':{
    text:'SOME_TEXT',
    date: 'SOME DATE'
  },
  'COMMENT2_REF_ID':{
    text:'SOME_TEXT_2',
    date: 'SOME DATE_2'
    }
  }
}
```

I should explain why we are not using "find" instead of "aggregate".
Our query should also sort and filter POSTS by COMMENTS and COMMENTS' TAGS fields. It seems like the virtual field can't be used for filtering or sorting purposes. Please correct me if I'm wrong (NOTE: we have a big amount of docs, and filtering data with backend (NodeJS+Mongoose) class/function would not work (too slow).

I would be interested to see any working examples based on the MongoDB pipeline.

Comment: Like this: [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L26tdqSdcOb)?

Comment: Thank you, Yong! Almost. $arrayToObject requires an object with keys 'k' and 'v', where the value of 'k' must be of type string. Our one contains regular "objectId"

Comment: I see, yes, if I am not mistaken the `k` most probably requires a `string` type (correct me if I am wrong), so the `ObjectId` cannot be used as `k`. You need cast the `ObjectId` to `string` such: `k: { $toString: "$$this._id" }`.